# passing a javascript value to form on submit of jsf button

Tags: javascript, jsf

i am trying to access a javascript varaible value from the javascript method and assing to jsf backing bean value and access in the controller on submitting?Thanks for your time

```
 function formValue(){
    var e = document.getElementById("formid:dropdownlist1id");
    var val = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    var e1 = document.getElementById("formid:dropdownlist2id");
    var val1 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;
    var result = document.write(val + ',' + val1);
    return result;              
    }
```

jsp page :

```
<h:commandButton styleClass="submitButton" value="search" 
    action="#{rController.method();}">
    <h:inputHidden id="hiddentext" value="#{rController.formidinput}"/>                         </h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Why don't you just bind the value of the two dropdowns to a backing bean property? You seem to be totally missing the point of JSF and working your way around it with unnecessary additional code.

Answer (score 0):

If `formid` is the form you are submitting, and you want to put the result of `formValue()` into the `hiddentext` hidden `<input>` field, then this should work.

If this is not what you want, then you might have to make your question a little clearer.

Javascript:

```
function setFormValueInHiddenField() {
    var value = formValue();
    document.getElementById("formid:hiddentext").value = value;
}
```

JSP:

```
<h:form id="formid" onsubmit="setFormValueInHiddenField();">
```

Comment: Hi Pauls, thanks for your reply, am trying to get those dropdownlist values selected by the user and based on 1st dropdown i will write my code to enable the jndi and then query sql based on the 2nd dropdown , with above code am submitting a form but its not going to controller method to do rest of the logic.I want to acces the user selected value from those dropdowns.

Comment: Yes Balusc, i just got the idea am working in the same manner having unccessasaryy.. Thanks any ways :-)

Comment: Right. I was trying to follow your example, but @BalusC points out the correct way. Wire up backing beans correctly and this should all 'just work'.